# What are the best practices for teaching second-language students in classes that have moved online mid-semester due to COVID-19?

Tags: literature-search, online-learning, covid-19

I'm working on a research project for one of my university's departments that supports professional development and teaching development for our faculty and grad students. We are expanding our resources focusing on online teaching, and I have found a lot of resources dealing with best practices of online teaching.

However, I haven't found much on supporting students for whom English is a second language in an online context.

I'd be very surprised if this research doesn't exist, but I haven't been able to find it so far through EBSCO, Google, etc. Most of the results I'm finding have to do specifically for teaching developmental English classes for students learning the language, but what I'm looking for is **resources on how professors in other subjects across the humanities and STEM fields can support their second-language students in this new all-online context** for this semester (and potentially next year).

**I'm interested in, for example, how can history or biology professors teach their online classes in a way that is easily accessible for students whose first language is not English?**

Note that the same issue probably exists for languages other than English.

Comment: Let me suggest that any technique that would improve comprehension for these students would almost certainly also improve it for native speakers. My solutions rely on using text, such as subtitles and transcripts for videos. This also aids the partially deaf as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is probably better on the Language Learners Stack.

Comment: @SolarMike and others, consider the fact that it isn't specifically about learning language, but about learning and teaching _other things_ when language difficulties (and online...) intrude.

Comment: @Buffy  clearly talks about ELL & ESL ... so seems **very** precise.

Comment: And the OP may benefit from the Italian Stack, French Stack as they both cover teaching...

Comment: @SolarMike I think you've misunderstand the question. Perhaps it could be better phrased as "What specific difficulties do second-language speakers of English have in taking online content classes, and how can we help?" This isn't about teaching English online. Frankly, I think online classes would be easier since they could rewind and slow recording, and have more written resources, but it's a good, on-topic question.

Comment: @AzorAhai I did not misunderstand ELL or ESL - the O P was very precise. As I pointed out they have their own stacks due to the focus they bring. However, if you are the OP then please rephrase the question correctly for clarity for me , and no doubt, others.

Comment: @SolarMike They are using ELL/ESL as a term for second-language speakers or to identify students involved in those services who also take content classes. "How do I teach biology to a second-language speaker of English after we've been forced online because of COVID-19?" is not an language learners question.

Comment: If this is a question about student accommodations, what practices are already in place to assist these students?

Comment: @AzorAhai I’ll leave it to you, although I have many nationalities on my courses and over 90 different in the institution.

Comment: @SolarMike I don't understand how that pertains?

Comment: @AzorAhai I spend most of my time teaching students who take the class in English which is for them their 2nd, 3rd or even 4th language so I have a good idea of what works for me.

Comment: @SolarMike I'm not sure I follow why you bring that up, but it sounds like you'd be in a good position to answer the OP's question, then.

Comment: @AzorAhai but as you know so much about the question I will leave it to you - especially as you think I don’t understand... looking forward to your answer.

Comment: @SolarMike Understanding a question isn't the same as having an answer. I don't have a lot of experience teaching L2 students.

Comment: @SolarMike I don't agree with your close reason at all.  Questions about teaching and learning techniques should be encouraged here.  Though it might be better if the question were more specific to higher education.

Comment: @jamesG could you explain why you think classroom pedagogy for English language learners should be different from online pedagogy for the same people?  It seems to me that the same strategies apply, such as explaining things in multiple ways, supplementing listening with reading and watching, language immersion, etc.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist you are free to agree or disagree with whatever you want - fill yer boots...

Answer (score 2):

> how can professors teach their online classes in a way that is easily accessible for students whose first language is not English?

Teaching online does not change the students' brains.  Use all the pedagogical techniques you would use in a lecture or discussion class that was not online.  They will still work.

One thing that can be easier online:  you can record your lectures.  This can be done for in-person classes, but typically online teaching software makes it easy.  Lecture recording allows English language learners to listen repeatedly, at their own pace.  Just keep in mind that some students need privacy to practice speaking.